# Performing a line integration given only a contour graph

Tags: integration

[image: Graph from problem]

A gradient vector field $\textbf{F} = ∇f$ and points
$P, Q, . . . , U$ on contour lines of $z = f(x, y)$
are shown in the above graph. Determine the value of the line integral
$\int_C \textbf{F} · d\textbf{s} $
when $C$ is the line segment from $U$ to $Q$ and
the values of $f(x, y)$ on the contour lines are
listed to the right.

I have never seen a problem of this sort and only understand how to perform these type of integrals if explicitly given functions with which to work, thus I am completely unsure of how to go about solving such a problem.

Comment: Do you know the family of equations for this graph? It looks like y=k/x.

Comment: This is all the information that is given in the problem... I thought that's what it looked like as well, but I still do not know how to progress further.